# Generating html code for drag and drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I want to provide an user of my application with a drag and drop feature. Say I have a div container where the user can drag and drop images present within the div to anywhere within the div. Something similar to http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/basic. But what I need is after the drag and drop has been completed, I want to extract the html code of the container div, so that I can store it and show it to the user at a later point of time, or use it elsewhere for some other purpose. There are a lot of jquery plugins for drag and drop, but I couldnt find any to generate the html code for the dragged elements. What could be the most straightforward way of doing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's fairly straightforward to extract the contents of a div with javascript.  If you're already using jquery you can simply do something like:

```
var contents = $('#draggedDiv').html();
```

or for regular javascript:

```
var contents = document.getElementById('draggedDiv').innerHTML;
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is with JavaScript, by storing the innerHTML of the dragged div in a JS variable.

```
var dragDiv;
dragDiv = getRefToDiv( 'drag-div-id' ).innerHTML;
...

<body>
<div id="drag-div-id">
<!-- the div's contents -->
</div>
</body>
```